Correlated Subquery Pattern is not allowed due to internal error
I'm working on amazon redshift where I'm trying to insert data from view to table.
e.g,
INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM VIEW1;

when I try to run this command it fails with below error
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Now when I only run select query it run fine. What could be the reason for the error, since the exact syntax is mentioned in documentation
Below is the view query
create or replace view schema1.tmp_v as 
with PP_WS_FLG as (
        select YM,
        case mod(substring(YM,1,4),2) when 0 then 'Y1' else 'Y2' end as DISP_YEAR_JAN,
        case mod(to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), -3),'YYYY'),2) when 0 then 'Y1' else 'Y2' end as DISP_YEAR_APR,
        substring(YM,5,6) as DISP_MON,
        substring(YM,1,4) || '/1 - ' || substring(YM,1,4) || '/12' as FILTER_1YEAR_JAN,
        to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), -3),'YYYY') || '/4 - ' || to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), + 9),'YYYY') || '/3' as FILTER_1YEAR_APR,
        case mod(substring(YM,1,4),2) when 0 then substring(YM,1,4) || '/1 - ' || (substring(YM,1,4) + 1) || '/12' else (substring(YM,1,4) -1) || '/1 - ' || substring(YM,1,4) || '/12' end as FILTER_2YEAR_JAN,
        case mod(to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), -3),'YYYY'),2) when 0 then to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), -3),'YYYY') || '/4 - ' || to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), + 21),'YYYY') || '/3' else to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), -15),'YYYY') || '/4 - ' || to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), +9),'YYYY') || '/3' end as FILTER_2YEAR_APR,
        case when substring(YM,5,2) < 4 then 'Q1' when substring(YM,5,2) < 7 then 'Q2' when substring(YM,5,2) < 10 then 'Q3' else 'Q4' end as WS_DISP_QUARTER_JAN,
        case when substring(YM,5,2) < 4 then 'Q4' when substring(YM,5,2) < 7 then 'Q1' when substring(YM,5,2) < 10 then 'Q2' else 'Q3' end as WS_DISP_QUARTER_APR,
        case when substring(YM,5,2) < 7 then '1H' else '2H' end as WS_DISP_HALF_JAN,
        case when substring(YM,5,2) >= 4 and substring(YM,5,2) < 10 then '1H' else '2H' end as WS_DISP_HALF_APR,
        substring(YM,1,4)  as WS_DISP_YEAR_JAN,
        to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), -3),'YYYY')  as WS_DISP_YEAR_APR,
        substring(YM,5,2) as WS_SORT_MONTH_JAN,
        to_char(add_months(to_date(YM,'YYYYMM'), -3),'MM') as WS_SORT_MONTH_APR
        from table1
)
select 1 demo from PP_WS_FLG;

create table schema2.tmp  (
    demo int
);

insert into schema2.tmp
select demo from
    schema1.tmp_v;

YM is string in the format YYYYMM

to understand what is happening we will need to see the definition of the view.  It likely involves Table1 is some way and seeing how should show the issue.

Added the view query

you have table1 in the first SQL but schema2.tmp as the table in the second code.  your CTE is unneeded as you are just selecting 1 as demo.  it seems like this still isn’t he whole picture.

Add the definition for table1. Start removing columns from the view one by one until you have the minimum possible reproducible code for the error. Then we can just copy and paste into our redshift to get the same error message. Until we can copy and paste your code block to throw the same error, neither we nor aws support can help you.

Hello I was able to solve the issue,
The schema1.tmp_v query was using view to refer to data and create a view. This created issue since the referred view was following the prohibited pattern
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html#r_correlated_subqueries-correlated-subquery-patterns-that-are-not-supported
